# Angular 2 Select Component set initial selection

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-forms

I am trying to create a select component wrapper in Angular 2 using ngModel. The events all fire off correctly once the selection is changed but I cannot set the initial selection when it's rendered.

This is my component:

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-dropdown',
inputs: ['selectedItem', 'items', 'label'],
outputs: ['selectedItemChange'],
template: `
<div class="field">
  <label>{{label}}</label>
    <select class="ui search selection dropdown" [ngModel]="selectedItem" (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
      <option value="" selected>Please Select</option>
      <option *ngFor="#item of items" [value]="item.value">{{item.label}}</option>
    </select>
</div>`
})

export class MyDropdownComponent {

items: DropdownValue[];
selectedItem: DropdownValue;
selectedItemChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

private onChange(newValue) {

    console.log(newValue);
    this.selectedItem = this.items.find(item => item.value == newValue);
    console.log(this.selectedItem);
    this.selectedItemChange.emit(newValue);
}
}
```

And I'm using it in the view like this:

```
<my-dropdown [items]="selectItems" [(selectedItem)]="itemToSelect" [label]="'Please Select'"></my-dropdown>
```

When I set the `itemToSelect` value in the parent component on init, it does not set the selected option value in the UI.

I have also tried to use the `ngModelChange` event but it does not fire a change event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`itemToSelect` is initially set to an object, so the input property of MyDropdownComponent is initially set to an object.  But then in `onChange()` a string value is `emit()`ted, which then causes `itemToSelect` to be set to a string, and hence the input property becomes a string.  Not good.

Just consistently use an object and it will work.  Also, there is no need to assign `this.selectedItem` in `onChange()`, since the selected value will propagate back down from the parent (in general, you should never set input properties in the component – it also looks weird). You can also use `ngModelChange` now too:

```
<select class="ui search selection dropdown" [ngModel]="selectedItem.value"
 (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">

private onChange(newValue) {
    console.log('nv',newValue);
    selectedItem = this.items.find(item => item.value == newValue);
    console.log('si',selectedItem);
    this.selectedItemChange.emit(selectedItem);
  }
}
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ORBXA59mNeaidQCLa5x2?p=preview)</kbd>

Note that I did not solve the issue of the user selecting "Please select".  You'll need to add some logic to `onChange()` to handle that case.

Comment: I'm studying your plunker example and the question I have is who or what is defining the type 'DropdownValue'.  When I move this code out of a plunke environment it's not defined.

Thanks....

Comment: @IrvLennert, that was a copy-paste error on my part (from the OP's code).  They're not needed (I removed them).  I used my own array of objects, assigned to `selectItems`, since the OP didn't show us the definition of the DropdownValue type.

Comment: @MarkRajcok this works but defining the ngModel on the actual selected item value `[ngModel]="selectedItem.value"` causes an error when the initial selection is not set, how would you prevent this?

Comment: @EnlitenedZA, set the selected item to a null value/object initially: `itemToSelect = {value: null};`

Comment: Be aware that u send an asynchron Event. First onchange will be triggered, than the binding, than the custom Event. You can create a synchron Event by creating it with new EventEmitter(false);

Answer (score 1):

> When I set the itemToSelect value in the parent component on init, it does not set the selected option value in the UI.

Assuming you are using `ngOnInit()` in the parent, you should set value in one of the [lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html) that are called later (because child doesn't yet exist in `ngOnInit()`), try `ngAfterViewInit()`...

Comment: I was using `ngOnInit` to set the selected item, changed it to `ngAfterViewInit` but it still is not setting the initial value in the UI.

Comment: Try also adding `ngOnInit` to MyDropdownComponent, and calling `onChange` from there.

Comment: Getting the following error: `Expression 'itemToSelect' has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: '[object Object]'`

Comment: That's a change detection issues, try changing `ChangeDetectionStrategy` for that component, just to confirm if it's working. You should really try to clean up/improve your logic because that's what's causing the issue. Parent is setting a value that triggers an event that's setting a value and emitting another event that's setting the first value... bit hard to follow (;

Comment: You could, for example, expand `[(selectedItem)]="itemToSelect"` to be one event and one property binding. `[selectedItem]="itemToSelect" (selectionChanged)="parentNotifiedAboutChange()"`

Comment: I'm not sure what logic can be improved - it is a wrapper for a select, you pass in the selectable items, and a reference to the selected item, when the parent item is set, it should update the UI, when the value is changed in the UI select it should change the bound parent model. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: It shouldn't matter that the child doesn't exist yet.  Angular should propagate the value to the input property when the child component is created (and it avoids the "___ has changed after it was checked" problem too).  If you were calling an API on the child component, that would be a different story.  See my answer for the solution, if interested.