# angular2 - reusable component - How to get initial value of a select box?

Tags: angular

I have a question like this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35597531/angular-2-select-component-set-initial-selection) but my reusable select component also gets the data from the server via a service.

I can get event changes, use ngClass etc...all is fine with the component.  Only issue is that that I want to get the initial value for the select and dont know how.

The initial value should be this object and is what I am trying to get:

```
selectedEnvironment = this.staging; //Intial Value
```

I can add a "Please Select" to force a change but I don't what do do that

Below is the html where I place my selector

```
{{selectedEnvironment | json}}
<environment (change)="onChange($event)" [useForm]="false"></environment>
```

So {{selectedEnvironment | json}} is empty on load but displays the object on change. The default property is set..I just don't know what it is.

I tried using:

```
[(ngModel)]="selectedEnvironment"
```

but I got this error:

> platform-browser.umd.js:962 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No value accessor for ''

So from my constructor

```
export class EnvironmentSelectorComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() useForm = false;
    isLoading = true;
    production: Environment = {
            id: '1',
            name: 'staging'
    };

    selectedEnvironment = this.staging;

    @Output() change = new EventEmitter();
    onChange(newValue:any) {
        this.selectedEnvironment = newValue;
        this.change.emit({newValue: this.selectedEnvironment})
    }

    environments = [this.staging];

    constructor(private environmentService: EnvironmentService) { }

     ngOnInit(){

        this.environmentService.getEnvironments()
            .subscribe(environments => {
                for (var i = 0; environments.length > i; i++) 
                { this.environments.push(environments[i])}

            },null,() => { this.isLoading = false; });
    } 
}
```

Here is the HTML for the component:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedEnvironment" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"
    [ngClass]="{'form-control': useForm}"
    class="custom-select">
    <option [ngValue]="i" *ngFor="let i of environments">{{i.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Implement `ControlValueAccessor` like explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37384373/angular-2-add-control-to-parent-components-form/37384802#37384802

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Günter you can implement `ControlValueAccessor` for that like this:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, OnInit, EventEmitter, Provider, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ControlValueAccessor } from '@angular/common';
import { Environment } from './environment';
import { EnvironmentService } from './environment.service';

const SELECTOR_VALUE_ACCESSOR: Provider = new Provider(NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, {
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => EnvironmentSelectorComponent),
    multi: true
});

@Component({
  selector: 'environment',
  providers: [SELECTOR_VALUE_ACCESSOR],
  template: `
    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedEnvironment" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"
      [ngClass]="{'form-control': useForm}"
      class="custom-select">
      <option [ngValue]="i" *ngFor="let i of environments">{{i.name}}</option>
    </select>`
})
export class EnvironmentSelectorComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {  
    isLoading = true;
    staging: Environment = {
        id: '1',
        name: 'staging' 
    };

    selectedId: any;
    selectedEnvironment: Environment;

    @Input() useForm = false;

    @Output() ngModelChange = new EventEmitter();

    onChange(newValue:any) {
        this.ngModelChange.emit(this.selectedEnvironment)
    }

    environments = [this.staging];

    constructor(private environmentService: EnvironmentService) { }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.environmentService.getEnvironments()
            .subscribe(environments => {
                for (var i = 0; environments.length > i; i++) { 
                    this.environments.push(environments[i])
                }

                this.selectedEnvironment = this.environments.find(x => x.id === this.selectedId);
            },
            null,
            () => { this.isLoading = false; });
    } 

    onModelChange: Function = () => {};

    onModelTouched: Function = () => {};

    writeValue(model: Environment) : void {
        if(!model) return;
        this.selectedId = model.id;
    }

    registerOnChange(fn: Function): void {
        this.onModelChange = fn;
    }

    registerOnTouched(fn: Function): void {
        this.onModelTouched = fn;
    }
}
```

And then you can leverage it like this:

```
 <environment [(ngModel)]="selectedEnvironment" [useForm]="false"></environment>
```

See also the working plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/xe824YAYpr2lMxgTvOK4?p=preview

Comment: Wow...I do not understand how that worked but it worked.  Where is the I am too stupid to live of all of the above?  I guess I have to take ang to the next level.